# Missing admin tabs in Zen Cart

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopping-cart, zen-cart

I am doing some small maintenance for a friend's eCommerce site. I have very limited knowledge of Zen Cart but I want want to add Coupons to his checkout.

I have installed the "Discount Coupon" module in "Order Total" and by all accounts I should have a tab in the Admin nav bar titled "Gift Certificates/Coupons"? But this tab is missing and nowhere to be found.

Upon further inspection I have noticed that many tabs and sub-menu dropdowns are missing. Is there anyway to re-enable these tabs or are they additional add-ons?

It should look like this...
[image]
But it looks like this...
[image]

I hope this is something small. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your friend has admin profiles installed, and that your profile doesn't have permission to look at the additional items.  See if you can go to tools->admin settings (you may need your friend to do this if your account is restricted).

Comment: Thanks - I found that some modules were uninstalled by the initial developer. Just a case of reinstalling